# Xcode & Swift Playgrounds empty console

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

I wanted to start something with Xcode/Swift Playgrounds, however when I clicked on "Run" the console is empty. I tried it with Xcode Playgrounds as well and it shows nothing.
I checked, there's no errors in my code. I'm confused. Should I delete Swift Playgrounds and try it over again?

(sorry about the indentation. I'm still new to stack) [image: Picture for reference]

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    Text("hello")
}

}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a weird bug of Swift Playgrounds. I can reproduce it if I open the console first, then click run. However, if I click run first, then the view shows up.

If you are in stuck in the "console is empty" state, try closing the playground and reopening it again from the "my playgrounds" page, then click run without opening the console.

Alternatively, deleting a character from your code and re-typing it also works for me.

Note that your code produces a SwiftUI view, so you are not outputting anything to the console. You are outputting to the "live view", which you can toggle by going to View -> Show Live View, or command + enter. However, doing this when you are stuck in the "console is empty" state will crash the whole app, which strongly suggests that this is a bug.